# Data insert problem within foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

The problem is that only some of the XML data is being Inserted into the my mysql database. 10 results are supposed to be entered into the database but it varies between 2 and 8 results.  I have no idea why it is doing this and I have tried adding a sleep function to slow the script down, but the data that is inserted into the data base is never as much as when I echo it out on screen.  Any help would be much appreciated..

```
function post_to_db($xml,$cat_id){

    if ($xml->Items->Request->IsValid == 'True'){

        $xml = $xml->Items->Item;

        foreach($xml as $item){
            $asin     = (string)$item->ASIN;
            $title    = (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Title;
            $content  = (string)
                             $item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview->Content;
            $sku      = (string)$item->ItemAttributes->SKU;
            $brand    = (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Brand; 
            $feature  = (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Feature;
            $model_no = (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Model;
            $review   = (string)$item->ItemLinks->ItemLink[5]->URL;

            $check = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `asin` = '$asin'";
            $checked = mysql_query($check);
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($checked);

            if ($numrows == 0){ 
                $query         = "INSERT INTO `products`".
                                   "(`cat_id`,`asin`,`sku`,`brand`,".
                                   "`model_no`,`title`,`content`,`feature`) ".
                                 "VALUES".
                                   "('$cat_id','$asin','$sku','$brand',".
                                    "'$model_no','$title',".
                                    "'$content','$feature')";

                $result        = mysql_query($query);
                $post_id       = mysql_insert_id();
                $review_page[] = array($post_id=>$review);  

            }
        }
    }

    return $review_page;    
}
```

Comment: why you put `'` around value like '$cat_id' , remove that

Comment: `Caps lock test: completed, pass.`

Comment: Have you tried `echo 'numrows = ' . $numrows;`?

Comment: @diEcho Those are MySQL quotes. They need to be there to insert the data using mysql_query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be some of your variables from XML are creating an invalid query (do they contain quotes?)

Instead of this for each variable:

```
$asin           = (string)$item->ASIN;
```

Do this instead:

```
$asin = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$item->ASIN);
```

If the problem still persists, change your `mysql_query` line to this for debugging:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks, for that - added mysql_real_escape_string and set some of the fields to default null and it now works well